# printable autofac documentation?

Tags: documentation, autofac

I can't seem to find anything printable about AutoFac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could print the wiki pages: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/w/list ?

Comment: Or a selection from http://api.autofac.org - but then, if it is available in digital format, why kill a tree?

Answer (score 1):

a bit late but this seems a pretty good doc for autofac.

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/autofac/latest/autofac.pdf